# How to implement recognizer on Android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

My software architecture as below:
TabActivity is a TabHost Activity.
It contain 2 ActivityGroup: AGroup and BGroup.
AGroup contain 2 Activities: A1Activity and A2Activity.

I want to implement recognizer in A1Activity.
My code as below:

```
    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNIZER_REQUEST_CODE = 0x1008;
public void Recognizera() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);

        if(activities.size() != 0) {
            try {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "語音辨識");
                startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNIZER_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(RequestCode) {
    case VOICE_RECOGNIZER_REQUEST_CODE:
        if(RequestCode == VOICE_RECOGNIZER_REQUEST_CODE && ResultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("results " + results.get(i));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, data);
}
```

But it show "Unknown problem" as the picture below URL.
[image]
But without any error message in logcat.
How to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because an error was encountered during the voice recognition. The `ResultCode` parameter will be the error code, one of the errors [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR). First find what is that error, so you can investigate it further.

Comment: It doesn't run to onActivityResult. So I cannot get the ResultCode.

Comment: Your `if` clause won't execute because the condition is never true, but are you sure `onActivityResult` is never called? Try adding this to the start of the method: `Log.d("Recognition", "Result code = " + ResultCode);`

Comment: I try to get the ResultCode at the first line in onActivityResult which before switch. But it does not show any log. So I think it never be called.

Comment: I try add same code at TabActivity. It works correctly. But in A1Acticity, itdoesn't work.